# WordPress settings page for custom methods

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress

I am fairly new to WordPress but I have semi-advanced knowledge of PHP.

I have been tasked with creating a converter, that takes "regular-db" data from an MSSQL server, and converts it into "WP-DB" data, using the post and postmeta table.

One of the things I have to make is a settings-type page for executing certain Stored Procedures on the MSSQL server, and there is no way to avoid it, so what I need is a WP settings page, that, upon filling some textboxes and pressing a button, will execute some PHP function that will, with the provided data, run the MSSQL Stored Procedures.

The MSSQL part is covered and I will not need help on that, all I need to know, is if/how I would go about creating this custom page and custom methods, and how I go about transmitting the data in a WP friendly way.

Best regards Troels

Comment: Check out the WP Settings API: https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API for creating the fields and this page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages for creating the actual pages.

Comment: Hey @TyBailey, thanks for the answer; I have read it, but it only says to set a forms action="options.php", and I dont know where to take it from there, or if it is okay to change the action link?

Comment: Hey @TyBailey, thanks again for the answer; based on your comment, I decided to re-read the pages more thoroughly, and found out what I needed, so thanks for your help!